# Mongoose find not returning the full collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to read data from an html form through a POST, store it in a mongoDB and query it using model.find() and print it in console. But when i run this for the first time the find() is returning an empty object and on giving the next input the previous data excluding the current input is retrieved by th find(). **How can i print the full collection including the freshly entered data**

```
 app.post("/", function(req, res){
      postTitle = req.body.postTitle;
      postDesc = req.body.postDesc;
      const post = new Post({
        title:postTitle,
        desc:postDesc
      });
      post.save();

      Post.find({}, function(err, data){
        if(err){
          console.log(err);
        }else{
          console.log(data);
        }
      });
      //console.log(postTitle, postDesc);
    });
```

Comment: can you show the console terminal output?

Comment: `[ ]`  _this is the output for console.log(data) after my first data save_  @Pardeep

Comment: you can use `GET` request to get the saved data

Comment: can you be more specific @kedarsedai

Comment: @VijayPD I added an es6 & async/await example to my answer for more efficient code writing. Also please accept my answer if it works so that others with the same issue can use the answer as well.

Comment: The first solution isn't working, but the solution using async works fine @JonathanNielsen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command `post.save();` will just begin working and your code will continue meanwhile. When your `Post.find({} ...` starts working, your `post.save();` haven't finished working, and thus you're not getting the results.

Change the function so you wait for the save to give you a callback with an ok and then you can query the database.

```js
app.post("/", function(req, res) {
    const postTitle = req.body.postTitle;
    const postDesc = req.body.postDesc;
    const post = new Post({
        title: postTitle,
        desc: postDesc
    });

    post.save(function(err) {
        if (err) {
            // Something went wrong with the save, log and return the error message
            console.error(err);
            return res.send(err);
        }

        console.log(`Post "${postTitle}" saved to database.`);

        // Since we know that the post has been saved, continue querying the database.
        Post.find({}, function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                // Something went wrong with the query, log and return the error message
                console.error(err);
                return res.send(err);
            }

            console.log(data);
            res.send(data);
        });

    });
});
```

This code is not tested.

You can also try async/await out, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function and also mongoose documentation for promises & async/await https://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html.

I myself would write the function like this using async/await and es6.

```
app.post('/', async(req, res) => {
    const post = new Post({
        title: req.body.postTitle,
        desc: req.body.postDesc
    });

    try {
        await post.save();
        const posts = await Post.find();
        console.log(posts);
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }

    res.end();
});
```

Comment: The first answer you provided isn't working. The solution provided using the async, await is working for my needs @JonathanNielsen

Answer (score 1):

You can try with exec

```
Post.find({}).exec(function (err, d) {
    if(err){
      console.log(err);
    }else{
      console.log(d);
    }
});
```

Or try to use `async` `await` to make sure your query is running step by step

```
const user_info = await Post.find({});
```

This code is not tested

Answer (score 0):

here post.save() is an async function that means it does not complete immediately. You need to use async - await in order to wait for the save() function to finish and then you query the database.

Comment: Even though you're right and it is a good approach like i specified in my answer, you can't say that he "need to use" it since there's multiple ways to handle the issue.